# A host invites n couples to a party, She wants

Tags: combinatorics

A host invites $n$ couples to a party, She wants to ask a subset of the $2n$ guests to give a speech, but she does not want to ask both members of any couple to give speeches. In how many ways can she proceed?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 4):

For each couple, there are three possibilities from which to choose:  husband speaks, wife speaks, or neither speaks.  The host thus has $3^n$ possible ways to choose a subset of speakers.  (Note:  this includes the empty set.)

Comment: (Not really a mathematical comment, but couples don't always consist of husband and wife.)

Answer (score 1):

- Choose a certain number of couple.
- Then choose which member of each couple will speak.

This give
$$
{n\choose k} {2\choose 1}^k
$$
if you have a fixed number of speaker in mind. If not, then you can sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {2\choose 1}^k= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} 2^k= 3^n
$$
where the last equality is from the binomial theorem. This agrees with @Barry's answer, provided you accept the empty set of speaker.

Comment: So is sum from k=0 to n of (2^k)*(n choose k) a correct way of thinking about it? We choose a group of size k, which can be done in n choose k ways, and then each of those people either speak or don't? It also equals 3^n but I am wondering if this is a way to think about it.

Comment: both my way and Barry's way are good way of thinking. His has the advantage of being really simple, while mine has the advantage of giving a quick solution if you are asked to choose, say, 7 persons to speak.  Note that we first fix a number $k$, and choose $k$ couples from $n$. We then need to choose exactly $1$ person per couple among THOSE $k$ couples. To get the general result, we then sum on $k$. This uses what is often called the principle of multiplication and the principle of addition in combinatorics.